# Dropzone.js FormData.append(key, value)

Tags: javascript, php

I am using `Dropzone.js` and everything is just fine. However, I would like to send some extra data as it is usually done through
`file.php?param=value&param2=value2`.

I read on `dropzone.js` API that you do it through `FormData.append(key, value)`. However, it does not seem to work. This is what I got so far

```
sending: function(file, xhr, data) {
    data.append('key', 'value');
}
```

and if I test it on php, it says that I put my code inside an `if($_POST['key'] === 'value')` which does not execute. On the other hand, if I remove the if it runs perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From your description, the data is gotten from the url `file.php?param=value`, so i think you should get it with : `$_GET['key']`

Comment: Thanks, but I was giving an example, when you use an URLand get method you use GET else you could use POST. But here what I am trying to accomplish is to pass some data on dropzone.js

Comment: Could you post you're code into JSFIDDLE?

Comment: I have tried posting the code on fiddle but it does not want to take the external resource. There is an example on the website ... http://www.dropzonejs.com/ Basically, I am looking to pass data when uploading info. Like you do when using url, (I am not using an URL, I am just giving you an example)